# List Update Error in a Recursion [Robot in a Grid] Python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I am doing this question from a book:

Robot in a Grid: Imagine a robot sitting on the upper left corner of grid with r rows and c columns. The robot can only move in two directions, right and down, but certain cells are "off limits" such that the robot cannot step on them. Design an algorithm to find a path for the robot from the top left to the bottom right.

And I wrote a solution for it, but it's not correct.

I printed out the path within the helper function.  It's all correct, but when it returned back the path_through_grid() function, it changed to something else.  I don't know what happened here.  Please help~

The following is the code I wrote:

```
def path_through_grid(grid):
  path = ["start"]
  helper(grid, 0, 0, path)
  print("final", path)
  if path[-1]=='end':
    return path
  else:
    return None

def helper(grid, r, c, path):
  print("start---", r, " - ", c, "path: ", path)
  if r == len(grid) or c == len(grid[0]):
    return
  if grid[r][c] == 1:
    return
  if r == len(grid)-1 and c == len(grid[0])-1:
    print("inside")
    path.append("end")
    return
  path.append("right")
  helper(grid, r, c+1, path)
  print("middle---", r, " - ", c, "path: ", path)
  if path[-1]=="end":
    print("inside 2", path)
    return
  path = path[:-1]
  print("after", path)
  path.append("down")
  helper(grid, r+1, c, path)
  print("end---", r, " - ", c, "path: ", path)

import unittest

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_path_through_grid(self):
    grid = [[0,1],
            [0,0]]
    self.assertEqual(path_through_grid(grid), ["start", "down", "right", "end"])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
path = path[:-1]
```

Here you assign to `path`, and that is an error. You should only mutate `path`, not assign to it. When you assign, the caller's `path` will not be affected any more -- you have now created a different list reference.

So instead, use an method that reduces the path's size

```
path.pop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved my life! Just to make sure I understand correctly.  When I use path = path[:-1], I created a new variable (a new reference) with the same name, and the original path will not be modified?